# How to set various row height in QTreeView (Qt, QML)?

Tags: c++, qt, treeview, qml

In my QML I have a TreeView:

```
TreeView {
                ...

                model: mProductions.getModel()

                TableViewColumn {
                    role: "name"
                    title: "Name"
                    width: root.width/4
                }

                TableViewColumn {
                    role: "image"
                    title: "Image"
                    width: root.width/4
                }
}
```

I need to have the row height higher in case the item has an image.
So I tried to use Qt::SizeHintRole in my data method for an item. But QML doesn't request this role.

```
QVariant Productions::TreeItem::data(int role) const {
    switch(role) {
    case NameRole:
        return QVariant(this->name);
    ...
    case Qt::SizeHintRole:
        return QSize(..., ...);
    ...
    default:
        return QVariant();
    }
}
```

So how do I force QML to request this role? Or is there another way to set different row heights? rowDelegate in QML didn't work for me.

Comment: For me using `rowDelegate: Rectangle {height: 25}` changes the height of the rows. Have you looked at this [example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols-filesystembrowser-example.html) to define `Roles`?

Comment: QML doesn't use the roles as QtWidgets do. You could Query the SizeHintManually but therefor you have to specify the roleName for Qt::SizeHintRole. Then you can Query it like any other Role.

Comment: Thank you. I haven't found any way to get any info about a specific item type from `rowDelegate`, so I'm only able to set height for all items. I tried different tricks with roles, but just faced some weird behaviour and no useful result.

Comment: Don't you have any other way of knowing whether your element contains an image?

Comment: I can provide any methods in my item model class or use role model to provide this information. The problem is that I can't access my model (the index of the element, to be exact) from `rowDelegate`.